# How to lock an exe file?

Tags: wpf, security, encryption

(Sorry in advance, if I have the wrong tags)

Hello!

So I am trying to work on a personal WPF project which would allow the client application exe to download another application exe (Unity Application) and open it within the client exe's Grid. Everything is working fine.

But, I am wondering if there's a way to "lock" the downloaded application in a way that only my client exe can open the downloaded exe?

Here's the only solution I have thought of but not sure with

1. Check for command line arguments within the Unity Applications
   This works well but people who knows about the existence of decompiler might be able to decode that I am trying to check the arguments, and input relevant data there. :(. So, it won't help too much?

Thanks for any insights.
-Kevin

Answer (score 0):

There is no non-hackable solution, you can only make it harder for crackers to break into the app by **code obfuscation** (hard to read the code) + adding **integrity checks** (make sure that your app is not modified).. There are commecial apps out there to do this (ex. [PreEmptive](https://www.preemptive.com/products/dotfuscator/)), and their solutions differ from each other, nothing is ultimate.

Anyway, You might make `Unity Application` read some file or some registry value that `Client application` has updated just before launching the `Unity Application`, along with command line args method that you mentioned..

Comment: Sorry for the late reply but thank you very much for your insights!